# How to use the RunOnUiThread on ContentPage on Xamarin Forms

Tags: multithreading, xaml, xamarin.forms, async-await

I want to use the RunOnUiThread for Update the UI (Chart and Label) with UI Thread by Timer. I am using the ContentPage. How can I use the Add the Activity class for RunOnUiThread on Content Page ? It's not supported.

I'd like to do the following:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => { tvTimer.Text = Convert.ToString(CountSeconds );});
```

Currently I am using the

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => });
```

for update the UI but UI is stucking or not updating properly like shows count down timer per seconds.

Please help me out

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: Add some delay about 100 miliseconds and then try Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => });

Comment: You can't use `RunOnUiThread` in Xamarin Forms. It's a function in Xamarin.Android. You could show more relevant codes to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think it is happening is that because you are probably doing some minor mistake and from the code that I see I cannot make that out so I will give a reference sort of thing for you to take a look on :

Define a method to be executed on the main thread:

```
 private async void MethodOnUIThread()
    {
       await **something**;
       //Probably your timer code 
       //This method does not necessarily have to be async.
    }
```

Run the method on Main thread something like this :

```
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(MethodOnUIThread);
```

Revert in case of queries or if you do not understand something